# Display the list when an item hover

Tags: html, css

I have this sample:

[link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qRmwjm)

```css
.show:hover .list-categories {
  max-height: inherit;
  opacity: 1;
}
.list-categories {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  max-height: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="show">show div</div>
<ul class="list-categories">
  <li>Bed</li>
  <li>Bed</li>
  <li>Bed</li>
  <li>Bed</li>
  <li>Bed</li>
  <li>Bed</li>
</ul>
```

this code does not work. I want to display the list when hover on the item ".show"

If you put the switch in the form (.show:hover +.list-categories) it works...but I want no plus sign.

How can I change this code without using the plus sign?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the adjacent sibling selector? It's exactly the way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your CSS you can change the HTML like BELOW.

```css
.show:hover ul.list-categories{
  max-height: inherit;
  opacity: 1;
}

.list-categories{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  max-height: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="show">show div
<ul class="list-categories">
  <li>Bed</li>
  <li>Bed</li>
  <li>Bed</li>
  <li>Bed</li>
  <li>Bed</li>
  <li>Bed</li>
</ul> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Adjacent sibling selectors `+` sign , for you reference check this link https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors

```css
.show:hover + .list-categories{
  max-height: inherit;
  opacity: 1;
}

.list-categories{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  max-height: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="show">show div</div>
<ul class="list-categories">
  <li>Bed</li>
  <li>Bed</li>
  <li>Bed</li>
  <li>Bed</li>
  <li>Bed</li>
  <li>Bed</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ok but do not want to use the selector to shape it(.show:hover + .list-categories) ... I want another form

Comment: @Cristi i don't understand can you explain me

Answer (score 1):

`+` will selects all `.list-categories` that are placed immediately after `.show` and `~` will selects all `.list-categories` preceded by a `.show`.

```css
.show:hover ~ .list-categories{
  max-height: inherit;
  opacity: 1;
}

.list-categories{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  max-height: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="show">show div</div>
<ul class="list-categories">
  <li>Bed</li>
  <li>Bed</li>
  <li>Bed</li>
  <li>Bed</li>
  <li>Bed</li>
  <li>Bed</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace your css with below css:

```
.show:hover+.list-categories{
  max-height: inherit;
  opacity: 1;
}

.list-categories{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  max-height: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease;
}
```

Comment: same problem as in the example above ... I do not want selector utilizes the "+"

Comment: oh! ok then add your ul into your div like my below code:

<div class="show">show div
<ul class="list-categories">
  <li>Bed</li>
  <li>Bed</li>
  <li>Bed</li>
  <li>Bed</li>
  <li>Bed</li>
  <li>Bed</li>
</ul>
</div>

and css is below:
.show:hover .list-categories{
  max-height: inherit;
  opacity: 1;
}

.list-categories{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  max-height: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease;
}

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you don't want the plus sign? With your html it is not possible. If you really dont want it, use this html.

```
    <div class="show">show div
<ul class="list-categories">
  <li>Bed</li>
  <li>Bed</li>
  <li>Bed</li>
  <li>Bed</li>
  <li>Bed</li>
  <li>Bed</li>
</ul>  
  </div>
```